# Не получается вывести данные в twig по ключу

Tags: php, twig

Изучаю twig, в виде такой код на PHP. Как вывести productsInCart.product['id']?
Как выводить массивы и обьекты понял, как из другого массива вывести по ключу в цикле хз! Надеюсь на "гуру" .

```
                    {% for product in products %}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ product.code}}</td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="/product/{ %product.id %}">
                                {{ product.name }}
                            </a>
                        </td>
                        <td>{{product.price}}</td>
              ! -->>>> <td><?php echo $productsInCart[$product['id']] ?>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: А что мешает написать {{ productsInCart[product.id] }}

Comment: С чего вдруг в твиге вы стали писать `<?php`?

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Надо спать !Я полночи извращался с массивами и for.Еще раз спасибо!

Comment: я показал что хочу вывести в твиге на PHP.Стандартно я могу вывести а шаблонизатор пока еще не разгрыз.В blade проще.